# Sticky Footer Error with CSS

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky

I've tried everything and can't seem to get the footer to stick to the bottom.

I've been moving things around, might have messed up the codes a bit.

I'm fine with how it is on longer (more content) pages. But it's giving me to much white space on pages with less content.

Help would be appreciated!

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

* {
 margin: 0;
}

/* Body */
html, body {
    font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
    background-image: url('mila_background_btm.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom; 
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 min-height: 100%;
}

/* Text */

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 color: #3A3366
}

h2 {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
 color: #2D4B5B;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
 margin-top: 1;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 150%;
}

/* Container */
.container {
 width: 90%;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}


/* Navigation */
header {
 font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
 width: 90%;
 height: 9%;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #312f47;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

nav {
 float: right;
 width: 70%;
 text-align: right;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-top: 35px;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #312f47;
}

a:hover {
 background: #312f47;
 color: white;
}

nav a:first-child {
 display: none;
}

.current {
    color: #9390A6;
}

/* Images */
.gallery {
   margin-bottom: 100px;
   height: 100%;
}

.photos {
  max-width: 50%;
}

.contact {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

/* Google Maps */
.google-maps {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 16.6%; 
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 50px;
 }
    
.google-maps iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 }
 
.video
{
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%;
 padding-top: 80px;
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.video iframe
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 15%;
 width: 70%;
 height: 70%;
}

/* Footer */
footer {
 font-size: 8pt;
 color: #707070;
    text-align: center;
 height: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<header>
<nav>
</nav>
</header>

</div>

<footer>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you want the footer at bottom of the page and don't move to up reference to page content ,check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You have no text between the footer tags that is why you do not see the footer and if you add background color it will be much more clear.

For example you should add  **class="site-footer"** to the html footer tag.

```
<footer class="site-footer">
  The Footer.
</footer>
```

And the class definitions in the CSS file:

```
.site-footer{
  height: 120px; 
  background: red;
}
```

You can also use the [link](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Add a min-height for `.content` relative to the viewport.

Decremented `110px` from it (padding-bottom: 50px; margin-top: 10px; footer height: 50px)

```
footer {
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #707070;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

* {
 margin: 0;
}

/* Body */
html, body {
    font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
    background-image: url('mila_background_btm.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom; 
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 min-height: 100%;
}

/* Text */

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 color: #3A3366
}

h2 {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
 color: #2D4B5B;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
 margin-top: 1;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 150%;
}

/* Container */
.container {
 width: 90%;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}


/* Navigation */
header {
 font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
 width: 90%;
 height: 9%;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #312f47;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

nav {
 float: right;
 width: 70%;
 text-align: right;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-top: 35px;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #312f47;
}

a:hover {
 background: #312f47;
 color: white;
}

nav a:first-child {
 display: none;
}

.current {
    color: #9390A6;
}

/* Images */
.gallery {
   margin-bottom: 100px;
   height: 100%;
}

.photos {
  max-width: 50%;
}

.contact {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

/* Google Maps */
.google-maps {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 16.6%; 
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 50px;
 }
    
.google-maps iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 }
 
.video
{
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%;
 padding-top: 80px;
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.video iframe
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 15%;
 width: 70%;
 height: 70%;
}

.container {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 110px)
}
/* Footer */
footer {
 font-size: 8pt;
 color: #707070;
    text-align: center;
 height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<header>
<nav>
</nav>
</header>

</div>

<footer>
  My footer
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you used position: fixed the footer stick bottom of browser page not at real bottom

Comment: It's not clear in the question that you want a "real bottom". What do you mean by that? By "real bottom" you mean right below <div class="content"> ?

Comment: im sorry its not my question , i meant in your answer that footer stick in bottom of browser  it's positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled

Comment: @mohade Check my answer again

Comment: ok go to jsfiddle and copy your code then add 
<div style='height:500px;'>test</div> under </header> and check what i'm say

Comment: It pushes your footer below viewport fold (which is expected) since height: 500px is greater than the viewport, right?

Comment: Not exactly how I wanted it to work. But it still works. It's just for a quick class assignment. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this for footer and its working perfect with me :

```css
html,body,ul,a,li{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  outline:none;
  vertical-align:top;
  height:100%;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.wrap{width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height:100%;margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  background:lightblue;}

footer{
  bottom:0px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;}

#fo-wrap{width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#FF2E99;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <div class='wrap'>
   here every thing in page
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div id='fo-wrap'>
      here footer content
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```